# Xcode 4 linking object files

Tags: c++, xcode, xcode4

I have started a new project consisting of one main.cpp file and an additional file + header. When I build it, it fails with a linking error, because xcode does not seem to link two object files. In Xcode 3 one simply had to add the other cpp to the main target. How does this work in Xcode 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found for my case. Was a problem with a template instantiation you obviously have to include them in most cases directly instead of compiling the definition separately.

Otherwise xcode seems to compile an link other source files in your project correctly.